# Are jquery deferred callbacks synchronous if the deferred is already resolved?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise, jquery-deferred

I'm guessing the answer's yes but the code's not the easiest to decipher. And in the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) it says

> Any callbacks added to the object with deferred.then(), deferred.always(), deferred.done(), or deferred.fail() are queued to be executed later. Calling deferred.resolve() or deferred.resolveWith() transitions the Deferred into the resolved state and immediately executes any doneCallbacks that are set.

But this doesn't explicitly cover the case of attaching a callback to an already resolved Deferred.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the promise is already resolved / rejected, the new callbacks are executed synchronously.

From the [`jQuery.deferred()` doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.deferred/):

> Once the object has entered the resolved or rejected state, it stays in that state. Callbacks can still be added to the resolved or rejected Deferred — they will execute immediately.

Demo ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DQAsk/1/)):

```
var def = jQuery.Deferred(),
    promise = def.promise();
console.log('before 1');
promise.done(function () {
    console.log('done 1');
});
console.log('after 1');
def.resolve();
console.log('before 2');
promise.done(function () {
    console.log('done 2');
});
console.log('after 2');
```

Output:

> before 1
>   after 1
>   done 1
>   before 2
>   done 2
>   after 2

Comment: Note however this is one of those aspects where jQuery promises **do not follow** [Promises/A+ specs](http://promises-aplus.github.io/promises-spec). AFAIK, both `Q` and `Bluebird` implementations would make sure the callback executes asynchronously (e.g. via `setImmediate`).

Comment: @Noseratio - interesting. I was considering switching to Bluebird, but that behaviour would in fact make some features harder for me to implement

Comment: @wheresrhys I can't see how having deterministic execution order over a random one would make it harder to implement any feature

Comment: @wheresrhys bluebird actually has a build (appropriately called Zalgo) that does this. You really really don't want to do this. It can make really "interesting" bugs.

Comment: I agree with @Esailija. I favor async execution as per Promises specs, as it narrows the gap for possible side effects and method reentrancy. On a side note: Esailija, well done on Bluebird, I'm a fan :)

Comment: @Esailijia - if the callback is synchronous it's guaranteed that any synchronous code called afterwards will not execute first, whereas if the callback is asynchronous then the other code will execute first. The exact case I'm thinking of is long-winded to explain, but it is definitely easier with synchronous; I have a jquery proof of concept working and it would need some refactoring to work with always asynchronous callbacks. I don't mean that the standard asynchronous way is objectively more difficult for every case.

Comment: @wheresrhys The only difference is that you are guaranteed a certain execution order, whereas with implementations like jQuery the execution order is not guaranteed. So it is simply absurd to say that such a guarantee makes something harder to implement.

Comment: @Esailija refactoring is harder to do than no refactoring

Comment: @wheresrhys I read that as - writing working code is harder than to stay with your code with race conditions that works only sometimes.

Comment: hello @wheresrhys, @Esailija, @Noseratio  and all, this topic is old, but still relevant. Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems that jQuery < 3 (the one with Zalgo) is deterministic - callback is invoked SYNCHRONOUSLY always. In above code snippet you can see that `done1` is executed *before* the 2 part (before2, done2, after2). It's not waiting for the next JS turn. Which makes it SYNC, not async. Or if I'm wrong, please, provide a more detailed code snippet that really proves that it's either async or sync, since the above looks 100% sync.